# How to properly concat string elements in 2-d ndarray in numpy?

Tags: python, string, numpy

In below code, I expect `arr2` return same list of string as `lst2`, but it doesn't. Why `lst2` and `arr2` are different? Is there any NumPythonic way to make `arr2` return same list of string as `lst2`?

code:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [['MI', '', 'P'], 
       ['B', 'N', 'SUFS'],
       ['KOS', 'XJRXA', 'JJHW'],
       ['ARI', 'TPKI', ''],
       ['VR', 'EYR', '']]

arr = np.array(lst)

arr2 = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: "".join(x), 1, arr)
lst2 = list(map(lambda x: "".join(x), lst))

print('lst:', lst)
print('arr:', arr.tolist())
print('lst2:', lst2)
print('arr2:', arr2.tolist())
```

output:

```
lst: [['MI', '', 'P'], ['B', 'N', 'SUFS'], ['KOS', 'XJRXA', 'JJHW'], ['ARI', 'TPKI', ''], ['VR', 'EYR', '']]
arr: [['MI', '', 'P'], ['B', 'N', 'SUFS'], ['KOS', 'XJRXA', 'JJHW'], ['ARI', 'TPKI', ''], ['VR', 'EYR', '']]
lst2: ['MIP', 'BNSUFS', 'KOSXJRXAJJHW', 'ARITPKI', 'VREYR']
arr2: ['MIP', 'BNS', 'KOS', 'ARI', 'VRE']
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not an improvement over simple row iteration.  It is not faster.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas will do it easily:

```
pd.DataFrame(arr).sum(axis=1)
```

The reason `np.apply_along_axis()` gives you trouble is that it infers the length of the strings in the result from the first row.  Since you end up with `MIP` in the first row, all the rows have a capacity of 3 characters which is not what you want.

There is a NumPy bug report for `apply_along_axis()` with more information: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8352

Comment: I didn't know first row decide the dtype of the array. I'll take pandas into account, but pandas is difficult for me... Anyway Thanks!

Comment: `np.array(lst,object).sum(axis=1)` works for the same reason that the `pandas` `sum` does.  `np.sum` applied to an object dtype array uses the '+' method of the objects, in this case Python strings.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.
I found the answer from https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8352#issuecomment-488133970
.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [['MI', '', 'P'], ['B', 'N', 'SUFS'], ['KOS', 'XJRXA', 'JJHW'], ['ARI', 'TPKI', ''], ['VR', 'EYR', '']]
arr = np.array(lst)

arr2 = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.asarray("".join(x), dtype=object), 1, arr)
# https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8352#issuecomment-488133970
lst2 = list(map(lambda x: "".join(x), lst))

print('lst:', lst)
print('arr:', arr.tolist())
print('lst2:', lst2)
print('arr2:', arr2.tolist())
```